# iPhone 5 charging sound keep repeating, why?

Tags: iphone, screen, charging

I am using my iPhone 5 for iOS development so it is attached to computer via cable and often when I hold it and rotate it to see screen in a different orientation and I accidentally **touch the cable at the neck**, Xcode warns me about lost connection, and the lightning sign disappear from iPhone screen on the top right corner and I can **hear this irritation charging sound**.

What can be the problem? The screen is a little bit scratched.

If I would replace screen would it solve the problem?

I have bought and tested with a brand new Apple cable.

Comment: Have you tried with a different cable?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds lightning cable or port related, not screen related.

Comment: I have been experiencing a similar issue and found that carefully cleaning my lightning port with a toothpick resulted in my cable being able to sit noticeably (in the neighborhood of 2mm) farther in the port. That seems to have helped the occasional disconnect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I brought iPhone back to Apple Service and the guy cleaned my iPhone at the plug with the needle that you can open the sim card tray. So he cleaned it, and that was lots of dirty coming out. And after all I have to claim connection is much more stable. So you should clean it first.

Comment: This completely fixed it for me.  A needle works, but I recommend using someting softer like a toothpick to prevent damaging it.

Answer (score 1):

Either because of a bad cable or a bad connector in the phone, you are disconnecting the phone by touching/moving the cable.

Either -
1. Don't touch it.
2. Try a new cable.
3. Worst case, will require a new charging port.

I just had this happen on my iPhone 5 and had a non Apple repair done for $50 at the familiar repair kiosks you find outside most Apple stores in the mall.

Answer (score 0):

Check your charging plug.  My plug was overheating, smelled like burning wires. Changed to another charger & chirping stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't believe it but some cleaning with a wooden toothpick fixed my problem. My IPhone 7 sometimes ignored being plugged in to a usb port, sometimes beeped every 3 seconds, but never charged the battery.
The toothpick fixed it and I didn't even try to be careful.